# Implementing a single linked list in C using recursion: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, recursion, singly-linked-list

The prompt for the program I am attempting to write says this:

> Create a linked list and a set of functions to operate it. All loops
> must be done using recursion. The following functions are the
> functions that the list will use:
>
> - isempty(): returns true if the list is empty, otherwise return true.
> - find(v): find a certain value and return its index. If it does not succeed return a value indicating a failure. This will require
>   recursion.
> - add(v): add an item with value v to the tail of the list
> - insert(i, e): insert an element e at index i. This will require recursion.
> - delete(n): remove an element at index n. If it does not succeed return a value indicating a failure. This will require recursion.
> - remove(v): remove the first instance of a certain value. If it does not succeed return a value indicating a failure. This will require
>   recursion.
> - replace(i, v): replace the value at index i with the value v. This will require recursion.
> - get(i): get the value at index i. This will require recursion
> - liststring(): returns a string of the list showing the values of each element in the following format: [value, value, ... , value].
>   This will require recursion.

I've written a similar program to this before, but I've never used recursion to navigate a linked list. I tried to adapt the original code I wrote for a linked list, but I'm getting memory leaks and segmentation faults every time I run the program. I found that the errors are occurring when trying to run a specific function, so I have attached the insert node function, main function, and struct used to store the nodes. Any tips on how to clean up the code, better diagnose my issues, or errors that you notice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_t {
    struct node_t *next;
    int value;
};

/**
 * @brief creates new node
 * 
 * @param value value to be stored in new node
 * @return pointer for new node
 */
struct node_t *create_node(int value) {
    struct node_t *node = (struct node_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));

    node->next = NULL;
    node->value = value;
    return node;
}

/**
 * @brief inserts node into linked list at index given by user
 * 
 * @param head pointer for node at front of linked list
 * @param index index/position of list to insert new node
 * @param value value to be stored in new node
 */
void insert_node(struct node_t *head, int index, int value) {
    struct node_t *tmp;

    if (index == 0) {
        tmp = head;
        head = create_node(value);
        head->next = tmp;
    } else if (head->next == NULL) {
        if (index == 0) {
            tmp = create_node(value);
            head->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = head->next->next;
        } else {
            printf("Index out of bounds.\n");
        }
    } else {
        if (index == 0) {
            tmp = create_node(value);
            head->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = head->next->next;
        } else {
            insert_node(head->next, index - 1, value);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct node_t *head = NULL;
    char choice, tmp;
    int index = 0;
    int value, num;

    printf("Please enter the index at which you want to insert a new element: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    printf("Please enter the value you want to insert: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    insert_node(head, index, value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the spec of is empty is wrong. Stopped reading after that.

Comment: @gnasher729 what do you mean exactly?

Comment: this is a lot of code, please create a [mre] .. pick one function and focus on that. Your trouble is with locating a node via recursion, it's nearly inconsequential what you do after you've located the node (erase it, change its value, insert after, etc). However you recurse to find a node will be very similar if not identical for each operation.

Comment: He probably means _`isempty()`: returns `true` if the list is empty, otherwise return `true`_ ... you mean otherwise return _`false`_

Comment: @yano should I edit the post so that instead it just shows a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with @yano about the MRE (re. just one function). We (I and many others) want a single `.c` that can be downloaded, compile cleanly, and be runnable on our systems (i.e. we can run it under `gdb` if we wish). If you had thousands of lines of code, then yes, it would need to be cut down. But, IMO, your file is small enough (e.g. 400 lines) to be an MRE. Cutting it down further would likely introduce more transcription errors (and we'd be asking you to add back functions).

Comment: The main problem I see has nothing to do with recursion.  It is that `insert_node()` does not provide the new head node to the caller.  Neither by returning it nor by accepting the list head as an in/out parameter.  Naturally, `main()`'s pointer `head` remains null.

Comment: Additionally, the code won't compile cleanly: (1) `ADD`, `EMPTY`, etc. are _not_ defined. (2) `delete_node/remove_node/replace_val` have return types of `int *` but you're returning (e.g.) `tmp` which is an `int` (i.e. _not_ `int *`). There's no `main` function so we can't see how the various functions are called. That is, you could have errors creating the list(s), adding to them, deleting from them, printing them. (e.g.) For example, your print code might be fine, but the print result is bad because the creation is broken.

Comment: Although it may not be what you want to hear, part of the problem is using recursion for this. Your recursive versions are vastly more complicated/convoluted than the non-recursive versions would be. I'd recode to use non-recursive versions. Then [and only then], if you must, use the non-recursive versions as a model for the recursive ones. Baby steps ...

Comment: This exacerbates the problem that `insert_node()` exhibits undefined behavior if the specified index is not valid for the list.  It attempts to step right through the terminating null `next` pointer if it reaches the end of the list, which it will do if `index` is greater than the number of elements or if it is negative.

Comment: @CraigEstey I don't have any choice in the matter of using recursion. I would prefer not to have to use recursion for this because the code would be cleaner and much easier to debug

Comment: @JohnBollinger would it be better if I just scrap this post and share the main function and all the functions that I have in one post? I was trying to do it by file due to using header files to separate my functions from my main function.

Comment: As I gather, your problem is recursively finding a node, correct? If so, then @CraigEstey I stand by what I said. Inserting, deleting, whatever other node operations,, don't need to be included in the question. Your post could be a `main` with a hardcoded linked list and a `findNodeRecursive` function that you need help with (that compiles cleanly, all that Craig said along those lines). And well it looks like John B has edited out a lot of your code, so some validation. If I've misinterpreted what you're asking, then nevermind on everything.

Comment: @yano my main issue right now is inserting a new node at a certain index specified by the user by using recursion. I'm able to insert the head of the list, but after that I receive segmentation faults. Until I can successfully insert new nodes I can't check any of the other functions.

Comment: What I was suggesting was do the non-recursive version first. Get that working. Then, copy-and-paste those functions, rename them, and convert them into recursive versions. You can then use the regular functions as a cross-check to help debug the recursive versions. It _may_ seem like more work to do that, but, IMO, it will be much easier in the end. When you get all working, you can just remove the regular functions. Or, just do (e.g.) `normal.c` and `recursive.c`, keeping them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a node into the list at index 0, that node becomes the list's new head node.  However, this function signature ...

> ```
> void insert_node(struct node_t *head, int index, int value) {
> ```

... provides no way to convey the new head node back to the caller.  As a result, `main()`'s head pointer always remains null.  There are 2.5 usual approaches to such issues:

1. return the new head node:

   ```
   struct node_t *insert_node(struct node_t *head, int index, int value)
   ```

   Of course, this requires the caller to do the right thing with the return value.
2. Use an in / out parameter to convey the list head to the function and enable it to set the new head directly:

   ```
   void insert_node(struct node_t **head, int index, int value) {
       // ... Work with *head ...

       // where appropriate:
       *head = new_head;
   }
   ```

2. (5.) Create a structure representing the overall list instead of using a bare head pointer.  Make the head pointer a member of that structure, and pass a pointer to the list structure:

   ```
   struct list {
       struct node_t *head;
       // and maybe other members, too, such as a tail pointer
   };

   void insert_node(struct list *list, int index, int value) {
       // ... Work with list->head ...

       // where appropriate:
       list->head = new_head;
   }
   ```

   This is really just a refinement of (2), in that the main point of both is that they add an extra level of indirection.

But that's only indirectly responsible for your memory errors.  The direct reason is that your `insert_node()` function assumes that the `index` value passed to it is valid for the list.  As it progresses through the list toward the specified index, it pays no attention to whether nodes' `next` pointers are null, so it will attempt to dereference a null pointer among these if the index is too large.  Or if the index is negative, as it decrements the index on each recursive call, and stops only when it reaches index 0.

You should validate that the index is non-negative, and you should watch for the end of the list as you progress through.  You should indicate an error somehow when the index is invalid, though I leave the details to you.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should have a function that does a recursive search for an index (and only a recursive search), and then you can call that to help perform all the other operations you need (insert, delete, modify, etc).  That may not always be the most efficient, but I think it will be the most straight-forward at least.  This is all you need for a recursive search:

```c
struct node_t* findNodeRecursive(struct node_t* head, int index)
{
    if (index <= 0) // treat negatives as 0
    {
        // here's the index we care about
        return head;
    }
    else if (head != NULL)
    {
        return findNodeRecursive(head->next, index-1);
    }
    // else
    return NULL;
}
```

Here's a possible implementation for `insert_node`.  I've used John Bollinger's 1):

```c
struct node_t* insert_node(struct node_t* head, int index, int value)
{
    if (index <= 0)  // treat negative index as 0
    {
        // special case, insert at the beginning
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            // nothing in the list yet
            head = create_node(value);
        }
        else
        {
            // head already exists, insert at new head
            struct node_t* newHead = create_node(value);
            newHead->next = head;
            head = newHead;            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // find the previous index
        struct node_t* prevNode = findNodeRecursive(head, index-1);
        if (prevNode != NULL)
        {
            // prev node exists
            // create new node to insert
            struct node_t* newNode = create_node(value);
            // check for error
            // insert the new node
            newNode->next = prevNode->next;
            prevNode->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

If possible, I'd change the indices to `unsigned` or `size_t`, since a negative index doesn't make sense (and will save you some error checking).  Here's an [end-to-end demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/77WxTTE4b) of `insert_node` in action.  You can use the same `findNodeRecursive` function to assist you with erasing and modifying nodes.  `insert_node` could be simplified even further from what I've shown if you treat negatives as 0.