# How to delete an element from a single linked list without traversing?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is the exact question:
Write an implementation of the delete_min_max routine below that deletes the maximum and minimum element from a linked list starting at “head” and returns the new head (if applicable) along with the deleted nodes corresponding to the minimum and maximum values. You can assume that all the linked list elements have distinct values. If the linked list contains only one element, the same element is considered both minimum and maximum. You are not allowed to call any function in your implementation. You can iterate through all the elements in the linked list exactly once in your implementation. Make sure that there are no syntax errors in your implementation.

This is the code I have written so far

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};

struct delete_info {
    struct node *head; // head of the new linked list
    struct node *min; // the deleted node that contains minimum value
    struct node *max; // the deleted node that contains maximum value
};

struct delete_info delete_min_max(struct node *head){
    struct delete_info delete;
    struct node* max=head;
    struct node* min=head;
    struct node* tmp=head;
    while (tmp!=NULL){
        if ((tmp->val)>(max->val)){
            max=tmp;
        }
        if ((tmp->val)<(min->val)){
            min=tmp;
        }
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }

    if (max->val==head->val || min->val==head->val){
        delete.head=head->next;
        head=head->next;
        if (head!=NULL){
            if (max->val==head->val){
            delete.head=head->next;
            head=head->next;
            }
        }
        if (head!=NULL){
            if (min->val==head->val){
                delete.head=head->next;
                head=head->next;
            }
        }
    }else{
        delete.head=head;
    }
    delete.max=max;
    delete.min=min;
    return delete;
}
```

I already traversed the element once to find out the maximum and minimum value. Now I need to delete these values within the same function but I can't traverse the list one more time due to restrictions given in the question. Also, I can't use double linked list according to the skeleton code provided in the question. How do I modify my function to include both deleting and searching for max and min values in a single loop.

Comment: As you traverse, using `tmp` as the current element, you want to remember/update a pointer to the _previous_ element. So, (e.g.) you need `struct node *max_prev = NULL; struct node *prev = NULL;` Then, as you traverse: `if (tmp->val < max->val) { max = tmp; max_prev = prev; } prev = tmp;` Likewise for `min`. The pointer to the previous element is what you'd get from a doubly linked list [embedded in the node struct] For background on what I mean, see my answer: [Issues with Linked List in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75954516/5382650) and the `replace_val` function

Comment: Don't delete any nodes until you finish the traversal, then use the information recorded to delete the min and max nodes. Remember to handle the corner cases with a) only one node, and b) first node needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the first traversal, also keep track of the nodes that *precede* the nodes that have the minimum and maximum value. For that to be possible, have a `prev` pointer follow *behind* your `tmp` (which I would rename to `curr`).

Then after the loop you'll have two pointers you can use to actually remove the node(s) that follow them. There are a few boundary cases to take care of:

- The list is empty. In this case you can immediately return three `NULL` values.
- One of the nodes to delete is the head node. In that case you don't have a *preceding* node. To work around this boundary case you could at the very start inject a dummy node before the current head node. Now you can have a pointer to a node that precedes the head node, and so it no longer is a boundary case. At the very end of the function you know that the head of the list is what ever follows after that dummy node.
- The two nodes are adjacent. In that case you have to take special care not to get mixed up while updating the pointers to delete those two nodes.

Here is how it could be done:

```
struct delete_info delete_min_max(struct node *head){
    struct delete_info delete;
    delete.head = delete.min = delete.max = head; // Initialise
    
    if (head == NULL) return delete; // 
    
    struct node dummy;
    dummy.next = head; // dummy node is prefixed before the list

    struct node* beforeMax = &dummy;
    struct node* beforeMin = &dummy;
    struct node* prev = &dummy;
    struct node* curr = head;
    
    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (curr->val > beforeMax->next->val) {
            beforeMax = prev;
        }
        if (curr->val < beforeMin->next->val) {
            beforeMin = prev;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    delete.min = beforeMin->next;
    delete.max = beforeMax->next;

    if (beforeMax == delete.min) { // min and max are consecutive nodes
        beforeMin->next = delete.max->next;
    } else if (beforeMin == delete.max) { // max and min are consecutive nodes
        beforeMax->next = delete.min->next;
    } else {
        beforeMin->next = delete.min->next;
        beforeMax->next = delete.max->next;
    }

    delete.min->next = delete.max->next = NULL; // Optional: detach from list
    delete.head = dummy.next;
    return delete;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch handling the consecutive nodes.  I had a more concise solution, but I missed that scenario in my test cases.